# How to run AltBeacon libraries foreground service properly

Tags: android, altbeacon

So, I'm using AltBeacon library and I found out from logfiles, that sometimes beacons are not detected. All issues were on devices with Android 8.0, so I automatically thought that it's because beaconManager is run as background service. Well, I brought application to background, waited 15 minutes, then brought it up and service was working as expected (beacon detection). But, the implementation is weird.

What I do is, I've `Service A` that is being run in foreground:

```
Intent serviceA = new Intent(this, ServiceA.class);
ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, serviceA);
```

So, lateron `Service A` calls `BManager` that initiates beacon manager as following:

```
beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(mContext);

beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().clear();
beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().
                setBeaconLayout("...")); 

beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(3000);
beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(3000);
BeaconManager.setRegionExitPeriod(11000L);
backgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(mContext);
beaconManager.bind(this);
```

I'm not sure if just because `Service A` is being run in foreground is beacon manager as well? I do set `setForegroundScanPeriod`, but I do not call `enableForegroundServiceScanning` how crucial is that? Is there a way I can see if beaconManager is being run in background or foreground (service)? How should I change my code to make sure that scanning is in foreground (what additional code I need to have)? Maybe I should split my `BManager` from `Service A` into other alternative (a hint and reason why that approach would be better).

I'll try to generate log files when possible, but as of now, maybe there's something to do from code perspective (maybe it's easy to see that something is very wrong with implementation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The code shown in the question won't work** to make the library scan as a foreground service.   Just because you make your own foreground service, doesn't mean that the library uses it to schedule scans.

By default on Android 8+, the library uses the job scheduler to run scans every 15 minutes in the background.  The foreground service alternative requires that the library's own scanning service be enabled and configured as a foreground service.  This does require calling `enableForegroundServiceScanning`, but theres more than that to setting it up.

The library's [documentation](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/documentation.html)  has a page for how to configure it as a foreground service [here](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/foreground-service.html).  You can also see an example of this in the library's [Reference Application.](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference)

I'd suggest you simply copy that setup code to get this to work properly.

Comment: Thanks for answer.
Is it possible to leave my own foreground service, but additionally add the extra code that is required for foreground service scans from your examples or I should extend Application class as it's shown in your examples? Also, is there an easy way to test if my new foreground implementation is correct (besides the notification)?

Comment: You are welcome to keep your own foreground service.  On Android, you can have one visible notification shared by multiple foreground services.  If you wish to start the library's foreground service from your foreground service, that is possible as well, although it does add to the complexity.  If your foreground service does not start for some reason, obviously the beacon scanning will also not start.